# What are the prerequisites to study Calculus on Manifolds.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, manifolds, differential-topology

I'm a bachelor degree math student who is interested in differential geometry and topology and doing my way through it. Recently I discovered the world of Calculus on Manifolds and I wish to know what are the prerequisists to studying it. I know that, besides a lot of Topology, Analysis and Linear Algebra, I need also some of Tensor Algebra (I don't know if it's the correct therm for it) and learning about the Wedge Product, Exterior Derivative and etc. However, I don't really know to where to get started.

I want to know if there is a recomendation to what subjects to studied first and some good references. I apologize if the english isn't proper or it was already been asked before.

Comment: Technically, your posted question goes beyond reference request.  However, despite that, I recommend that you add the *reference-request* tag to your posted question.  Beyond that, I upvoted your question because I think the question is both very well written and very legitimate.  However, other MathSE reviewers may react negatively to your question, because it is a challenging (i.e. *inconvenient*) question to deal with.  Inconvenient questions don't typically fare well on MathSE; there is no quality control on the reactions of MathSE reviewers.  Anyway, I am totally ignorant in your area.

Comment: @user2661923 Grateful for your advise, I've already added the reference-request

Comment: A "standard" text for bedrock knowledge about smooth manifolds needed for global analysis, differential geometry / topology, etc. is John M. Lee's [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9982-5). It is fairly self-contained in that it treats, say, things like the basics of multilinear algebra required and should be accessible to anybody with a basic background in analysis, topology and linear algebra.

Comment: @BenSteffan Thank you for the reference.